# Using OOP results in heavy objects? Will they be slow?

Tags: oop

I'm using OOP to write small games with different types of characters (e.g. platformers, shooters) that do different types of things. I typically try to spread out functionality into easily manageable, simple classes (e.g. an `Environment` class would perform common physics calculations for all its `Inhabitants`, so they don't need to worry about that). But, it seems that the more I refactor these programs to align with OOP principles, the heavier my character objects get. Since they're the ones with the important data, they use their own data to perform functions on themselves. This keeps them decoupled from things outside of their realm, but makes their classes seem to grow and grow. I'm totally comfortable with breaking these character classes down into more manageable components, but I worry that having many objects onscreen that are instantiated from classes with a lot of methods will result in a slow-running game.

1) Do the number of instance methods on an object directly impact its runtime performance?
2) Am I using OOP correctly if I end up with heavy character objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. Or at least mostly no, anyway.
2. Maybe, but probably not.

For a character-based game, it's perfectly reasonable that a character would have a lot of associated data. Efficiency is rarely affected by representing that as a single "flat" collection of primitive objects, or a tree-like collection of a few large objects, each of which (recursively) has a number of smaller constituent parts.

As far as number of methods affecting performance: the number of methods can affect cache utilization, especially if you have (for example) lots of extremely small methods, and heavily-used methods are more or less interleaved with less used ones, so you end up with a lot of cache space devoted to less-used methods because they happen to be in the same cache line with something that's used more. Being methods affects this primarily because a compiler will typically arrange methods of the same class close to each other in memory, so sharing cache lines becomes more common. At least with typical implementations, however, calling a method will be O(1), so the number of methods doesn't directly affect speed.

Comment: With the i7 line of processors cache misses is not something a novice programmer designing non-system software has to worry about :D, even the ARMS in phones these days have sufficient cache for simple software. But yes, that is the truth of the matter :D

Answer (score 1):

- No, its not what methods you have in an object, but what you do with them that increases runtime cost. Ofcourse there is a limit to this, but with current hardware you can completely forget about it. However, it is often questionable to go beyond a dozen or two members in a class from a design standpoint. Splitting your objects up doesn't need to incur any significant cost, you can inline all your getters and setters, and pass values by pointers and references. The compiler can flatten all your design decisions out and mostly the code from a "heavy" class is equivalent to code from a constellation of small classes
- Correctly in this context is entirely dependant on the taste of the people developing the code. The processor doesn't care about what software engineering design decisions you make. If you wan't to make you objects all encompassing and it feels right to you then do it. There might come a point where things don't feel "right" to you, at that point you might split things up.